# asbestos in the garden?

Tags: asbestos

I was out in the garden today and came across quite a few bits of material resembling the attached image.

It's a bluey/grey color and has these thick white strands coming out of it.

It doesn't look like any asbestos i have seen, however, the fibres are a bit concerning.  In addition, I also cracked a piece and it snapped very clean and easy.

Has anyone seen this type of material?

[image]

Comment: Looks like old cat poop with bird bones in it to me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The picture is of a small part, however, there are larger parts resembling the base of plant holder or something similar.  Looks like it's been broken up into smaller parts.  Thanks again for the response though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asbestos doesn't grow on trees.  For garden ID questions maybe try outdoors.stackexchange.com

Comment: Nobody, but _nobody_ can tell if it's asbestos just by looking at it. The only way to know for sure is to get it tested. Also, unless you've been actively ripping it to shreds and breathing deeply the resulting dust cloud, you're most likely just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Probably fiber reinforced plastic or fiber reinforced concrete, based on the comment suggesting "resembling the base of plant holder or something similar." Plastic would be reinforced with glass fiber, concrete would be reinforced with plastic fiber. If you're not in Russia it would be ancient to be reinforced with asbestos, and it does not look like asbestos-cement (a very common product way back when) at the breaks - the fibers are huge.

Anyway, you can have it tested, or not breathe it. The latter is pretty easy in soil, where asbestos is also found simply from having been there a few million years, in small percentages.